# How to download/attach source code in Intellij 12

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver

I had created a new project in Intellij 12 version ,which is a maven module.I have selected autoscroll options from the IDE too.But when I hover to WebDriver using Ctrl Q it prompts me to download /attach source code.I tried downloading/attaching but no change shows and WebDriver.class opens up instead of WebDriver.java.

Also note that this is happening for my new projects only ,for old selenium version like 2.39.0 it shows fine,it prompts me to attach for only 2.41.0 selenium dependency.

Message that shows is "Source not found" in the IDE.Why is it only for 2.41.0 selenium version and not for 2.39.0?

Comment: Check your Maven POM. You might added 2.41 dependency instead 2.39

Comment: Yes My POM has dependency for 2.41.0.But my question is why am I able to attach sources in 2.39.0 but not in 2.41.0 ?

Comment: How did you attached the source code for 2.39 ?

Comment: it got attached automatically ..since it was thru maven but this doesnt happen for 2.41.0..In 2.41.0 when I do Ctrl Q for source code say on WebDriver ,it shows me the WebDriver.class instead of WebDriver.java and asks me to attach source code..source not found

Comment: Do it manually then , Please find the below answer.

Comment: Doing it manually certainly works, but I still question IDEA's "Download..." (renamed in IDEA 14) feature, because I have _never_ seen it actually find the sources of what I'm looking at.

Answer (score 3):

In order to add sources choose:

```
1.File | Project Structure
2.Click Libraries tab
3.Pick library and click + icon
4.Find a JAR file containing sources.
```

But in your case,( using maven as a build tool), IntelliJ will automatically download and attach available source to all libraries, no manual work needed.

**Update:**
Feel free to do the following step to update the indexes so that idea know that we have done the above change.

File > Invalidate Caches/Restart -> click invalidate and restart

Comment: I agree but am confused why isn't Intellij automatically attaching the source file to the libraries for 2.41.0 dependency added in POM.It does fine for 2.39.0

Comment: I have no idea. Could be jar issue. As it works for other versions,we cannot balme intelliJ idea.You got to find this and report.Anyway, i hope your question "How to download/attach source code in Intellij 12" is answered.

Comment: I followed the steps but it shows the jar files already added.Then why doesnt it link me?

Comment: If the source JAR is attached but IDEA is not "seeing" it when trying to resolve sources, the most likely cause is the indexes for that JAR are corrupted. Go to _File > Invalidate Caches_ and then restart IDEA. Let it re-index the project (Progress bar is in the lower right). That should resolve the issue.